# extending class and its data member

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns

I have a class `A` that has a data member `data` of type `base_data`. I would like to extend `A` to `B` by inheritance, but at the same time extend `A::data` to a derived type `derived_data`.

One possible design for that is to declare `A` as a template class, accepting as parameter the type of `A::data`.

```
struct base_data {
};

struct derived_data : public base_data {
};

template <class DataType = base_data>
struct A {
    DataType data;
};

struct B : public A<derived_data> {
};
```

The problem with this design is that, strictly speaking, `B` is not derived from `A<>`, hence functions that involve an `A<>` object would not compile with a `B` type. Example:

```
void f(A<>&&) { }
void f(const A<>&) { }

A x, y;
f(x);
f(std::move(y));
B xB, yB;
f(xB); // Error
f(std::move(yB)); // Error
```

One workaround is to declare `f` as template function

```
template <class T>
void f(A<T>&&) { }
template <class T>
void f(const A<T>&) { }
```

This however has the drawback that `f` can be called with any `A<T>`, which may not be desirable.

Another approach would be to constraint the argument of `f` to be either `A<>` or `B`

```
template <typename T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, A<>> || std::is_same_v<T, B>>>
void f(const T& a) { }

template <typename T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, A<>> || std::is_same_v<T, B>>>
void f(A<>&& a) { }
```

This is also not very elegant. Essentially, the part of a code that contains functions using `A` now must know that it could also use a sort-of-derived class `B`, perhaps defined elsewhere. Also, if there are many of such functions, one has to modify all of them to template functions as above. And if another sort-of-derived class C is added, one has to update all declarations of `f` and similar.

A third option would be to provide explicit conversions from `B` to `A<>`

```
template <class DataType = base_data>
struct A {
    DataType data;
    A() { }
    A(B&&) { }
    A(const B&) { }
};
```

But again, this implies that the code of `A` must know its sort-of-descendant `B`. Even worse, the copy conversion `A(const B&)` may be expensive and defies the simple idea that a const reference can bind to a derived class, without additional overhead.

Is there a good/better design pattern for this problem?

Comment: Are B and A in the relationship: B "is a" A? It doesn't seems to be in the way you are describing it, they don't share the same data. This let me think that they share functionality, so, you might need to have an abstract class in the middle (if you want dynamic polymorphims). Or just have a single template class that accept the data to act upon.

Comment: The problem with A about knowing about its descendant can be solved by curiously recursive template with a trait class. But generalizing function so reference can point to derived class? if the choice is runtime, you need dynamic polymorphism. ANd maybe, in some cases, virtual inheritance